# Why does my prime number generating function generate a bunch of zeroes?

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks, primes

I've been trying to get back into coding, especially in C. So I've used Project Euler for project ideas, and I took on the one about the 10001st prime. However, when I run the code below, it returns 2, 0, 0, 0, etc. What is the problem? I have looked at the questions asked by others, but I didn't find any in as low a level language as C.

```
/*##########################################################
*   The 10,001st Prime
*   Rob Merrell
*   21 January 2016
##########################################################*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int Int = 2; int PrimeCheck = 2; int Count = 0; int PrimeCount = 0;
    int Primes[10002]; Primes[0] = 0;
    if (Int < PrimeCheck) {
        for (Int = 2; Int < PrimeCheck;PrimeCount < 10001) {
            if (PrimeCheck%Int != 0) {
                Int++;
                continue;
            }
            else {
                PrimeCheck++;
                Int = 2;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        Count++;
        Primes[Count] = PrimeCheck;
        PrimeCount++; PrimeCheck++;
        Int = 2;
    }
    int i = 1;
    for(i = 1; i < 10001; i++) {
        printf("%d ", Primes[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int Int`? My eyes! They burn!! Take it away!!!

Comment: Since `Int` is not less than `PrimeCheck`, the first block of code never runs, so you never find all the primes. You just run the `else` clause, which increments `Count` one time, and just sets `Primes[1]`.

Comment: Er... Your function does not generate any primes besides the very first one. That's exactly what you see in the output. Typically, when you have to generate many numbers, you'd have some kind of *cycle* in your code (explicit cycle or recursion or something else). You don't have anything like that in your generating code. How do you expect it to generate many numbers then?

Comment: Maybe you intended to have a loop around the whole thing?

Comment: Or maybe `if (Int < PrimeCheck)` should be inside the `for` loop.

Comment: [Here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#C) is decent prime generator in C

Comment: @Barmar But the `else` clause has a PrimeCheck++, so shouldn't that mean that the next time, (Int < PrimeCheck)?

Comment: There is no next time. That `if` statement is not in a loop, it just runs once when the program starts.

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger to see what lines get executed in what order. That would have shown you that there is no next time.

Answer (score 0):

You question is more about problem solving, then programming in C (or any other language), given that your method of approaching the problem is buggy as others have noted in the comments.  Here is a way to think about this problem:

So, if I asked you to do that problem by hand, how would you do it?

Most likely, you would do something like:

- (step 1) Pick a staring test number, say 4 (knowing that 2 and 3 are prime numbers)
- (step 2) Set a trial divisor to 2
- (step 3) If your number is evenly divisible by the trial divisor go to step 7
- (step 4) Increment your trivial divisor by 1 and step 3.
- (step 5) Write down the next number as it is prime,
- (step 6) Check to see if you've found 10001 primes, if so end.
- (step 7) Increment your test number by one and go to step 2

So, in pseudo-code the above would look something like this:

```
primeCnt <- 2
testNum <- 4   

while (primeCnt <= 10001) do
    divisor <- 2
    isComposite <- false 
    while (divisor < testNum)
        if(testNum % divisor == 0)   // we found a factor  
            isComposite <- true
            break
         end if
         divisor <- divisor + 1
    done

    if (!isComposite)     // we found a prime
        primeCnt <- primeCnt + 1
        print  testNum
    end if

    testNum <- testNum + 1

done
```

You should be able to translate the above pseudo-code into C.  Obviously, the above code is not optimized.

A few things I learned about Project Euler #7 -

1. expect to encounter large numbers, you will be well advised to use unsigned 64-bit integers to avoid integer overflow.
2. The above algorithm, while correct is not very efficient, and will take a very long time to run.  You may want to use it to find the first 20 or so primes to verify that it works (and then look for optimizations).
3. When I solved it I used that fact that prime numbers are either one less then or one greater then a multiple of six (excluding 2 and 3).  See [this link](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/six.html) for the proof of this statement.